# Including files in subdomains

Tags: php

I was able to include files with the following values when my site was at www.mysite.com...

```
$BaseINC = '/home/username/public_html';
include ($BaseINC."/2b/file.php");
```

However, I've moved my site. It's now a subdomain on another URL - subdomain.newsite.com. Now that I've published my site as a subdomain, the above include scheme doesn't work.

I've tried various schemes, like /subdomain/new-username/public_html, /home/new-username/public_html/subdomain, but I'm missing something.

To make sure I understand the difference between linking from a subdomain to a subdomain vs linking from a subdomain to the main domain, imagine if I published the same file to the following locations:

1) www.newsite.com/2b/file.php

2) subdomain.newsite.com/2b/file.php

Could someone show me how to modify this...

```
$BaseINC = '/home/username/public_html';
```

...so that it connects me to the file (file.php) hosted on the domain AND also show me how to modify it so that it includes the file (file.php) hosted on the subdomain? If I know the correct path for both, then it should all make sense. ;)

P.S. If there's a better way to do it, I'd appreciate knowing about it.

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ? or even magic constants `__DIR__`

Comment: Is this new site hosted on the same server as the old site?

Comment: Yes, it's on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including files from a different server may cause some security issues on your site, anyways if you really want to do this you can always edit your php.ini configurations and turn on **allow_url_include** and then you can use the following to include your code:

```
<?php include http://subdomain.yourhost.com/file.php ?>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. A domain and its subdomain would be on the same server, wouldn't they? In fact, I used to include files between different websites, not knowing it was a bad practice. One day, my sites all crashed, and I discovered my webhost had nixed the inter-site includes. But I asked tech support if I could include files between a subdomain and its master domain and they said that's no problem.

Comment: If the main website and the subdomain is hosted in the same machine then you can include it using the local path i.e:

<?php include '/path/to/file.php' ?>

Answer (score 0):

If cURL is available, this might be an option...

```
$BaseURL = 'http://subdomain.domain.tld';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $BaseURL."/path/to/file.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

You may see issues if curl isn't able to retrieve the file. If the remote file isn't changed often, you can incorporate some caching. In which case you would save the file locally and use cron to download the file in the background and check it against the cached version.
Using cron would also help with timeouts and such so you could just include the file locally.

Another option may be to use htaccess.